# Command dotnet not found

Tags: .net-core

I have installed a fresh Windows10, and downloaded the "dotnet-install.ps1" from Microsoft:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-install-script

And I ran it by:

```
powershell -Command "& '...\dotnet-install.ps1' -Channel 7.0 -Runtime windowsdesktop"
```

It returned success, and now if I rerun:

```
> .\dotnet-install.ps1 -Channel 7.0 -Runtime windowsdesktop
dotnet-install: Note that the intended use of this script is for Continuous Integration (CI) scenarios, where:
dotnet-install: - The SDK needs to be installed without user interaction and without admin rights.
dotnet-install: - The SDK installation doesn't need to persist across multiple CI runs.
dotnet-install: To set up a development environment or to run apps, use installers rather than this script. Visit https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download to get the installer.

dotnet-install: .NET Core Windows Desktop Runtime with version '7.0.2' is already installed.
dotnet-install: Adding to current process PATH: "C:\Users\daniel\AppData\Local\Microsoft\dotnet\". Note: This change will not be visible if PowerShell was run as a child process.
```

It says it's already installed.

However, when I try running my application:

[image]

Trying to run `dotnet`, but it's not found (neither from cmd, nor from powershell).

Tried rebooting the machine, then retry running this script, it keeps telling me it's installed, but I don't understand, what is going on.

Comment: Please try to install `dotnet` via supported installer: https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download (as recommended by the script).

Comment: Also - have a look on https://github.com/microsoft/PowerToys/issues/20266 for more context if the problem persist after manual installation